# how to disable multiple form buttons on form submit and still have correct action performed

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form with multiple submit buttons.  I simply want to disable them once either is pressed, and everything works fine until I 'disable' them in the .submit() JQuery handler, in which case the form no longer appears to send the button name/value information along with the form.  How can I disable the buttons but still have the button name/value submitted so I can determine which one was pressed?

The Form

```
<form action="myaction" method="post" name="sendgift" id="sendgift" > 
    ....input, etc ....       
    <input type="submit" name="_action_go" value="Looks great! Do it" id="sendgiftbtn" />
    <input type="submit" name="_action_index" value="I need to make changes" id="gobackbtn" />
</form>
```

The JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#sendgift").submit(function() {

       //if I remove these two lines, everything works
       $("#sendgiftbtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       $("#gobackbtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        console.log("disable buttons called");
        return true;
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case instead of disabling the buttons add a `disabled` class and check for this class whenever you `submit` the `form`. If the class is present just `return false` else `true` and before returning `true` add the `disabled`class to all the `buttons` of type `submit`.

```
 $("#sendgift").submit(function(e) {

        if(!$(e.target).hasClass('disabled')){
            //if I remove these two lines, everything works
            //$("#sendgiftbtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            //$("#gobackbtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            //console.log("disable buttons called");

            $(this).find('input[type=submit]').addClass('disabled');

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Defined the `disabled` button style as

```
.disabled{
  padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
  border: 2px outset ButtonFace;
  color: GrayText;
  cursor: inherit;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't change the appearance of the buttons however.

Comment: You can make the button look disabled by setting styles in `disabled` class. I have add the required styles to my answer hope that helps.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes more sense.  Thanks.

Comment: Ended up going with this solution.  Thnx.

Answer (score 2):

The disabled attribute removes the element from form submission by design: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

**3 approaches:**

1. If you want to make it "appear" that the form element is disabled
   you can have js store the value of the field in a hidden variable
   `<input type='hidden' value='[the value of the disabled field]'
   name='[name of disabled field]' />` and then disable the visible
   input.
2. You can also try styling the field as disabled and add an onfocus event that `blur()`s the field any time a user tries to modify it again.
3. You can add an onsubmit event to the form that un-disables any
   inputs with the disabled attribute set, so that they are submitted
   as normal.

Comment: +1, important to make note that this behavior is by design in HTML, not jQuery specific.